# Proving that the torque is equal the vector product of the magnetic moment and the magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

Supposing that $B$ is a uniform field over the space, i want to prove that the torque $\tau = M \times   B$

$d\tau = r \times dF = r \times (I dl \times B ) = I [r \times (dl \times B)] = I[ dl (r \cdot B) - B (r \cdot dl)] $

$\tau = \int_{C closed} I[ dl (r \cdot B) - B (r \cdot dl)] = \int_{C closed} I[ dr (r \cdot B) - B (r \cdot dr)] = \int_{C closed} I[ dr (r \cdot B) - 0.5 B d(r \cdot r)] = \int_{C closed} I dr (r \cdot B) = I \int_{C closed} (dr) (r \cdot B)$

Now my motivation to go thought this way was believing that i could use stokes theorem in the end. But as you can see, i have a vector (dr) and a scalar $(r \cdot B)$, so there is no way to use stokes. How to go on from where i stopped to get the answer?